# Can't open Designer view in Visual Studio after renaming

Tags: visual-studio, editor, designer

Just after renaming in the Solution Explore Form1.cs to frm_main.cs I can't open the designer.

Do you know how to recover it ? Is-it a bug in Visual Studio 2015 ?

[image]